# Difference between ways of creating branches in git

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, versioning

Can anybody explain me about the difference between following two procedures:

1. Creating a new branch from existing one in git & then Editing it followed by committing.
2. Editing an existing branch & creating new branch before committing it & commit the changes in newly created branch.

M sure they are different, but exactly how, would like to find out.

Comment: we dont normally follow the 2 in practise

Comment: @MillerKoijam.. I'd like to know why so? Coz I use 2nd one

Comment: we create a new branch to start a new task. when fully tested and changes are stable, we merged it to the main branch. hope this might help you http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: and what if you open the main branch, edit it, see if it is stable, if yes then go for new branch else discard everything.. Sorry but your point does not have a real point.

Comment: that is what we try to avoid. we don't work directly on main branch. we only merged branches to main branch. see the link in my last comment. The sole purpose of the branch is to test a new functionality and merged when it is fool proof that it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the end result.

Changes which are in the working directory and changes staged in the index do not belong to a branch. When you create and switch to a new branch, your uncommitted changes are not touched.

Comment: ... and that's probably all that matters.

Comment: Till today, I also thought both are same.. Had to ask this question because when I opted for second way today, the files i created while editing are included in both existing & new branch. Any explanation for this? @StephenC n MattBall

Comment: @achievelimitless: that suggests you forgot to `git add` the new files, so that they are untracked in both branches, and therefore remain in the working directory when switching branches.

Comment: @achievelimitless - yes.  It suggests that you did something wrong in the way that you switched from your existing branch (with edits) to the new one.  I think we'd need precise and accurate description of the sequence of actions/events before we could give you an accurate explanation.

Comment: @achievelimitless: got me, I avoid most GUIs and have barely touched Xcode.